# Signing clickonce using Sectigo SHA384 EV certificate give unknown publisher and smartscreen blocker

Tags: clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to sign the clickonce application using Sectigo Sha384 EV Certificate using SafeNet client.

Below is a snapshot from SafeNet

[Safenet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaFh7.png)

Steps I am following

PLEASE NOTE CSP in SignTool is CSP in SafeNet client while CSP in Mage is KSP in SafeNet client. Mage was not signing otherwise.

I am using VS 2022, but not using its UI to sign anything during publish. I am signing the clickonce artifacts afterward

SignTool version 10.0.22621.2428
Mage version 4.8.9032.0 used from location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools

```
//STEP 1: Signing exe file
signtool.exe sign /v /fd "SHA256" /as /f $certPath  /csp "eToken Base Cryptographic Provider"  /kc "[{{tokenpass}}]=Sectigo_xxxxxxxxxxx" /td "SHA256" /tr "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" "c:\publish\1.0.0.0\App.exe"

//STE2: Updating the file hashes in the application manifest file
mage.exe -Update "c:\\publish\\1.0.0.0\\App.exe.manifest" -FromDirectory "c:/publish/1.0.0.0" -Algorithm "sha256RSA"

//signining application manifest
mage.exe -sign "c:\publish\1.0.0.0\App.exe.manifest" -CertFile $certPath -CryptoProvider "SafeNet Smart Card Key Storage Provider" -KeyContainer "[{{tokenpass}}]=Sectigo_xxxxxxxxxxx" -TimestampUri "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" -Algorithm "sha256RSA"

//Verify signing application manifest
mage.exe -Verify "c:\publish\1.0.0.0\App.exe.manifest"

//Updating the deployment manifest with the location and hash of the application manifest
mage.exe -Update "c:\publish\App.application" -AppManifest "c:\publish\1.0.0.0\App.exe.manifest" -Publisher "Test Publisher"

//Signing the deployment
mage.exe -Sign "c:\publish\App.application" -CertFile $certPath -CryptoProvider "SafeNet Smart Card Key Storage Provider" -KeyContainer "[{{tokenpass}}]=Sectigo_xxxxxxxxxxx" -TimestampUri "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" -Algorithm "sha256RSA"

//Verify signing deployment manifest
mage.exe -Verify "c:\publish\App.application"

// Copy the deployment manifest to the versioned path
Copy-Item "c:\publish\App.application" "c:\publish\1.0.0.0\App.application"

//sign the bootstrap file
signtool.exe sign /v /fd "SHA256" /as /f $certPath  /csp "eToken Base Cryptographic Provider"  /kc "[{{tokenpass}}]=Sectigo_xxxxxxxxxxx" /td "SHA256" /tr "http://timestamp.sectigo.com" "c:\publish\setup.exe"
```

I have also checked that publisher name is visual studio in description is  "Test Publisher" which matches with whom certificate is issued.

[vs settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCPFC.png)

I am getting a unknown publisher pop up

[unknown publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFkPN.png)

I am also getting smartscreen blocker while installing clickonce application.

I was hoping a clean install with known publisher and without any smart screen. That is why I choosed EV certificate

I have also checked the certificate, it is valid and have proper chain

Comment: Any brave takers of this question? getting error of "unknown publisher" while installing it on my window 11 pc and few other  windows 10 or 11 pcs first time.
However if I try to install it on the same server (windows server 2008 R2) where it is deployed, It shows publisher name perfectly fine. It is getting very frustrating.

Comment: There is a post here
[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ClickOnce-EV-Signing-with-HSM/10278648](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ClickOnce-EV-Signing-with-HSM/10278648)
which talks about - Your key is an “[exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.keynumber?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-keynumber-exchange)” key. Mage supports only “signature” keys.
Is it still true as i can sign manifests without an error.
I can see my EV token also have AT_KEYEXCAHNGE as key specification

Comment: It is something with Sectigo timestamp server. While signing manifests using mage.exe I dont think it using RFC 3161 timestamping url http://timestamp.sectigo.com is choosing appropriate signature algorithm.  Try signing with http://timestamp.sectigo.com?td=sha256 gives error related to endpoint not reachable.

So I replaced it with http://timestamp.digicert.com?td=sha256 and unknown pblisher away on first install on windows 11 goes away. I wonder how it was showing publisher name on server it was deployed.
But now after install when it still shows me SMARTSCREEN blocker, I have to allow.

Answer (score 0):

1. It was something with sectigo timestamp url, digicert timestaping url has fixed the "unknown publisher" problem. It is perfectly okay to use timestamp url across signing authorities
2. I misunderstood it when I said I had an EV certificate. It was actually an OV certificate and smart screen pop is well anticipated there until it start gaining on trust slowly.